# How to expand expression in bash to get multiple commands separated by ;

Tags: bash, awk

Lets say I want to create file1.txt, file2.txt ... file9.txt in a single line command and write the string "TEST" in all of them. I don't want to use for loops. I want to write an expression that will expand into something like:

```
echo "TEST" > file1.txt ; echo "TEST" > file2.txt ; ... ; echo "TEST" > file9.txt ;
```

If I write `echo "TEST" > file{0..9}.txt` it will not work because it will expand only the right side. Is it possible and how do I get it to repeat entire command together with `;` at the end for each separate file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To write the same content to many files, you can use the `tee` command.  Supply the file names as arguments, provide the content on standard input, and discard the output:

```
$ tee <<<'TEST' file{1..9}.txt >/dev/null
$ more *| cat
::::::::::::::
file1.txt
::::::::::::::
TEST
::::::::::::::
file2.txt
::::::::::::::
TEST
::::::::::::::
file3.txt
::::::::::::::
TEST
::::::::::::::
file4.txt
::::::::::::::
TEST
::::::::::::::
file5.txt
::::::::::::::
TEST
::::::::::::::
file6.txt
::::::::::::::
TEST
::::::::::::::
file7.txt
::::::::::::::
TEST
::::::::::::::
file8.txt
::::::::::::::
TEST
::::::::::::::
file9.txt
::::::::::::::
TEST
```

Comment: Nice. Been shell programming for 35+ years and never knew tee could take multiple output files - thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Using `awk` you can do this easily:

```
awk '{print "TEST" > $1; close($1)}' <(printf '%s\n' file{0..9}.txt)
```

---

Or, using `printf | xargs`:

```
printf '%s\n' file{0..9}.txt | xargs -I % bash -c 'echo "TEST" > "$1"' - %
```

`awk` solution is preferred as it doesn't spawn `bash` for each file.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{while(++i<=10){close("file"count".txt");print "TEST" > "file"++count".txt"}}'
```

---

---

***Explanation of above code:***  Adding explanation for above code in points.

We are not reading any Input for `awk` command. `BEGIN` section of `awk` command will be executed before any Input_file is given to `awk`.

Then in `BEGIN` section I am running a `while` loop which runs from value of `i=1` to till value of `i=10`.

Inside loop I am first checking if any output file named `filecount.txt` is opened then close it. Since we are making only 10 output files so at this time NO error will come but in case you want to create N number of .txt output files so to avoid errors "Too many openeed files one" this `close` is there.

Now print comes where I am printing string `TEST` into file name `file`(a string) `count`(a varibale whose value get increment each time by 1) `.txt`(a string).

Comment: @Nebeski, could you please check if this had help you too?

Answer (score 0):

Without loops and in parallel, with **GNU Parallel**:

```
parallel 'echo TEST > file{}' ::: {1..9}
```